Kernel Double Fault When Loading IDT - OS dev
I'm encountering a double fault in my kernel when loading the Interrupt Descriptor Table (IDT). The interrupt handler outputs the following error:
Got Signal: Double Fault (4144)

Since a double fault should always have an error code of 0, the non-zero value 4144 suggests there may be issues with my ISR routines.
Relevant Code
kinit.S
[extern kmain]
[extern kernel_stack]
[global _start]

KERNEL_STACK_SIZE equ 4096
DATA_SEG equ 0x10

section .kinit

_start:
  mov ax, DATA_SEG
  mov ds, ax
  mov es, ax
  mov ss, ax
  lea ebp, [kernel_stack + KERNEL_STACK_SIZE] 
  mov esp, ebp

  cld
  call kmain

  jmp $

kmain.c
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdint.h>

#include "idt.h"
#include "vga_screen.h"

#define KERNEL_STACK_SIZE 4096
__attribute__((aligned(16))) uint8_t kernel_stack[KERNEL_STACK_SIZE];

void kmain() {
  clear_screen();
  init_idt();
  for (;;);
}

isr.S
[extern irq_handler]
[global isr0]
[global isr1]
[global isr2]
[global isr3]
[global isr4]
[global isr5]
[global isr6]
[global isr7]
[global isr8]
[global isr9]
[global isr10]
[global isr11]
[global isr12]
[global isr13]
[global isr14]
[global isr15]
[global isr16]
[global isr17]
[global isr18]
[global isr19]
[global isr20]
[global isr21]
[global isr22]
[global isr23]
[global isr24]
[global isr25]
[global isr26]
[global isr27]
[global isr28]
[global isr29]
[global isr30]
[global isr31]

isr_common_stub:
    pusha

    mov ax, ds
    push eax

    mov ax, 0x10
    mov ds, ax
    mov es, ax
    mov fs, ax
    mov gs, ax

    cld

    lea eax, [esp]
    push eax
    call irq_handler
    add esp, 4

    pop eax
    mov ds, ax
    mov es, ax
    mov fs, ax
    mov gs, ax
    popa

    add esp, 8
    iret

%macro isr_with_err 1
isr%+%1:
    push %1
    jmp isr_common_stub
%endmacro

%macro isr_no_err 1
isr%+%1:
    push 0
    push %1
    jmp isr_common_stub
%endmacro

; Division Error
isr_no_err 0
; Debug
isr_no_err 1
; Non-Maskable Interrupt
isr_no_err 2
; Breakpoint
isr_no_err 3
; Overflow
isr_no_err 4
; Bound Range Exceeded
isr_no_err 5
; Invalid Opcode
isr_no_err 6
; Device Not Available
isr_no_err 7
; Double Fault
isr_with_err 8
; Coprocessor Segment Overrun (Deprecated)
isr_no_err 9
; Invalid TSS
isr_with_err 10
; Segment Not Present
isr_with_err 11
; Stack-Segment Fault
isr_with_err 12
; General Protection Fault
isr_with_err 13
; Page Fault
isr_with_err 14
; Reserved
isr_no_err 15
; x87 Floating-Point Exception
isr_no_err 16
; Alignment Check
isr_with_err 17
; Machine Check
isr_no_err 18
; SIMD Floating-Point Exception
isr_no_err 19
; Virtualization Exception
isr_no_err 20
; Control Protection Exception
isr_with_err 21
; Reserved
isr_no_err 22
; Reserved
isr_no_err 23
; Reserved
isr_no_err 24
; Reserved
isr_no_err 25
; Reserved
isr_no_err 26
; Reserved
isr_no_err 27
; Hypervisor Injection Exception
isr_no_err 28
; VMM Communication Exception
isr_with_err 29
; Security Exception
isr_with_err 30
; Reserved
isr_no_err 31

idt.c
#include "idt.h"

#include <stdint.h>

#include "irq_handler.h"

#define CODE_SEG 0x8

__attribute__((aligned(16))) idt_entry_t idt[IDT_ENTRIES_COUNT];
idt_register_t idt_reg;

idt_entry_t make_idt_entry(uintptr_t irq_handler_addr) {
  return (idt_entry_t){.low_addr = irq_handler_addr & 0xFFFF,
                       .selector = CODE_SEG,
                       .always0 = 0,
                       .flags = 0x8e,
                       .high_addr = irq_handler_addr >> 16};
}

void load_idt() {
  idt_reg.base = (uintptr_t)&idt;
  idt_reg.limit = IDT_ENTRIES_COUNT * sizeof(idt_entry_t) - 1;

  __asm__ __volatile__("lidtl (%0)" : : "r"(&idt_reg));
  __asm__ __volatile__("sti");
}

void init_idt() {
  install_irq_handlers();
  load_idt();
}

the interrupt frame struct
typedef struct {
  uint32_t user_ds;
  uint32_t edi;
  uint32_t esi;
  uint32_t ebp;
  uint32_t ignored_val;
  uint32_t ebx;
  uint32_t edx;
  uint32_t ecx;
  uint32_t eax;
  uint32_t int_num;
  uint32_t err_code;
  uint32_t eip;
  uint32_t cs;
  uint32_t eflags;
} interrupt_frame_t;

For a minimal reproducible example, please refer to my GitHub repository: SafeMemoryZone/ssos
Question
Why am I receiving a double fault with a non-zero error code when loading the IDT, and how can I fix potential issues in my ISR routines?

You are not getting a double fault. You are getting a timer interrupt which is by default mapped to irq #8. You should remap the hardware interrupts. See also osdev, in particular: "Some interrupts mapped by the 8259 by default overlap with some of the processor's exception handlers. These can be remapped via the 8259's IO ports."

related: How does the BIOS distinguish Interrupt(08h-12h) from INT instructions, vs. actual exceptions inside the CPU? re: the bad design decision in the IBM-PC of using interrupt numbers that Intel's 8086 manual documented as reserved for future use.  Like 8 for double-fault, which wasn't a thing in 8086 but was later.  (@Jester)
